# spring-boot-maven-plugin include source folder

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

Might be a stupid question but I have a spring boot project that I want to package into a jar file, which is quite easy but I also want to depend on the project which is where the problems starts appearing.

So I have this in my pom file which makes the jar file runnable:

```
  <build>
    <finalName>${project.name}</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

The issue is that if I look in the built jar file under `$HOME/.m2` I can only see spring packages and not my own packages in the root of the jar file.
This seems to make it so that it cannot be imported correctly by other maven projects.

If I on the other hand remove that build plugin, my packages start appearing in the root of the packaged jar file and it can be imported correctly. However it is then missing a manifest file and thus isn't executable.

So I guess the question is: can I force my packages into the built jar package as well as keeping the spring boot stuff in there?

Comment: Have you tried `spring-boot:repacakage `?

Comment: A spring boot application is not intended to be used by other projects cause the resulting jar file is not consumable on the classpath. If you like to create modules which can be used by others you have either to go via a multi module build or separated individual project..

Comment: @mallikarjun I tried adding the goal `repackage` as a execution in that plugin, but no luck.

Comment: @khmarbaise Yeah, that kind of makes sense... but I am doing this via a multi-module build that is breaking for some reason. One of the modules is depending on the spring module

Comment: refactor the code out into a separate module...that's the way to go..